# I want my code in the start button to run continuously when I press start and stop running when I press stop

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I want my code in the start button to run continuously when I press start and stop running when I press stop.Can somebody tell me a way through which my time and values change continuously on the GUI screen? Here is what I wrote:

```
% --- Executes on button press in start.
function start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to start (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

global loop;
loop=1;
while loop==1
voltage1=50;
curr=1;
pf=0.8;
power=voltage1*curr*pf;
y=sprintf('Voltage: %d V, Current: %.2f A, Power Factor: %.2f, Power: %.3f W',voltage1,curr,pf,power);
set(handles.voltage,'String',y);
t=datestr(clock);
set(handles.date,'String',t);
rate=66.5;
z=sprintf('Rate: %.2f Rs',rate);
set(handles.rate,'String',z);
end

% --- Executes on button press in stop.
function stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to stop (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
loop=0;
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use 'global'. When using global, you need to declare it in each function: declare `global loop;` inside `stop_Callback` function too. Also try, to add small pause like `pause(0.01)' somewhere inside the while loop (it gives Matlab time to respond to `stop_Callback`).

Answer (score 0):

The following example demonstrates start and stop buttons.
I used the following: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/about-the-simple-programmatic-gui-example.html example, to create a GUI without using **guide**.
The reason for not using **guide**, is so you can execute the example without need for the **fig** file, created by **guide**.
Keep using **guide** - it is much more simple than creating GUI by code.

Instead of using global variable, I saved 'loop' state in `handles.h_figure.UserData` (it is saved in field of GUI object).

The following example, (just) changing start button colors, until pressing stop:

```
function simple_gui2
    % Create and then hide the GUI as it is being constructed.
    h_figure = figure('Visible','off','Position',[360,500,450,285]);

    % Initialize the GUI.
    h_figure.Units = 'normalized';

    movegui(h_figure, 'center')

    % Make the GUI visible.
    h_figure.Visible = 'on';

    h_start = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
                        'String','Start','Position',[100,150,250,80],...
                        'Callback',@startbutton_Callback);

    h_stop = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
                       'String','Stop','Position',[100,50,250,80],...
                       'Callback',@stopbutton_Callback);

    handles.h_start = h_start;
    handles.h_stop = h_stop;

    % Start Push button callback.
    function startbutton_Callback(source, eventdata) 
        %global loop;
        %loop = 1;

        %Instead of using global variable, save loop in UserData element of figure.
        loop = 1;
        handles.h_figure.UserData = loop;

        while loop == 1
            %Set start button color to random color
            set(handles.h_start, 'BackgroundColor', rand(1, 3));
            pause(1);
            loop = handles.h_figure.UserData;
        end        
    end


    % Stop Push button callback.
    function stopbutton_Callback(source, eventdata) 
        %global loop;
        loop = 0;
        handles.h_figure.UserData = loop;

        %Set start button color to white color
        set(handles.h_start, 'BackgroundColor', [1, 1, 1]);
    end
end
```

Please notice: You may need a small pause (I used a second pause) between each iteration of the loop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this task you can  use 'UserData' property of Stop button. 
When Start button is pressed set  'UserData' of stop button to 0 and than in while loop check this value. When the Stop button is pressed set 'UserData' to 1 which will break while loop.
Here is the example:

```
function start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.stop,'UserData',0);
set(handles.start,'Enable', 'off');
set(handles.stop,'Enable', 'on');

while (get(handles.stop,'UserData') == 0)
    % Your code
    pause(1)
end

function stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.stop,'UserData',1);
set(handles.start,'Enable', 'on');
set(handles.stop,'Enable', 'off');
```

In this example I make Start button enabled off when it is pressed and back to enabled on when Stop button is pressed (the same is for Stop button), which I think is preferable in point of view UI design.
Note that, value of pause can be even shorter(for example pause(0.00001)).